# 複数列を条件に新たな列を追加したい

Tags: python, pandas

python初心者です。pandasで以下のことをやりたいです。

```
|A|B|C|
|OK|OK|OK|
|-|OK|NG|
|OK|NG|OK|
```

といったデータフレームがあった場合
A,B,C列がすべてOKだったら、新規に追加したnew列にOK
それ以外はNGとしたい。

```
|A|B|C|new|
|OK|OK|OK|OK|
|-|OK|NG|NG|
|OK|NG|OK|NG|
```

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

データフレームということなのでPandasの前提で解答します。
（DataFrameの準備までのコードを質問に書いてもらえると解答しやすいです）

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [True, np.nan, True],
        'B': [True, True, False],
        'C': [True, False, True],
    })
>>> df.all(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
>>> df['new'] = df.all(axis=1)
>>> df
      A      B      C    new
0  True   True   True   True
1   NaN   True  False  False
2  True  False   True  False
```

---

追記.
True/False ではなく 'OK'/'NG' という文字の場合は以下のようにできます。
速度より分かりやすさ優先でコードを書きました

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['OK', np.nan, 'OK'], 'B': ['OK', 'OK', 'NG'], 'C': ['OK', 'NG', 'OK']})
>>> df
     A   B   C
0   OK  OK  OK
1  NaN  OK  NG
2   OK  NG  OK
>>> df.replace('OK', True, inplace=True)
>>> df.replace('NG', False, inplace=True)
>>> df
      A      B      C
0  True   True   True
1   NaN   True  False
2  True  False   True
>>> df['new'] = df.all(axis=1)
>>> df
      A      B      C    new
0  True   True   True   True
1   NaN   True  False  False
2  True  False   True  False
>>> df.replace(True, 'OK', inplace=True)
>>> df.replace(False, 'NG', inplace=True)
>>> df
     A   B   C new
0   OK  OK  OK  OK
1  NaN  OK  NG  NG
2   OK  NG  OK  NG
```

Comment: 何から何までありがとうございます！
一度OKをTrue、それ以外をNGに置換する必要がありますね。
がんばってみます。

Comment: OK, NG の文字に対応したコードにしてみました

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事に実装できました！